# Using same domain name and SSL on different platforms

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, tls, domain-name, godaddy

I have a site hosted on godaddy, I have also purchased a domain (something.co) and SSL from godaddy and used on godaddy site. And that site is our marketing sort of site.
Our main product resides on AWS beanstalk, which includes backend services as well as a portal on mean stack.
Now, The question is that can I use the same domain name and SSL certificate on our portal deployed on AWS beanstalk while also being used on our godaddy site?

Comment: It should be obvious that "www.example.com" can only mean one thing, or one collection if identical things, but cannot mean two or more different things (e.g. "facebook.com" is exactly one collection of identical things -- no matter which server you hit, the response does not vary), so the answer to your question *as currently phrased* seems to be "no," even though the answer to the question you intend to ask is probably "yes" ...but if you could clarify what this specifically means to you in real terms, perhaps we can solve the actual problem.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot In actual terms I intend to reuse the domain name and the SSL certificate, but dont want to change the location of resources from godaddy and aws. Thats the only requirement

Answer (score 1):

This is possible (but arguably not desireable).

The first way to to do this would be to deploy a reverse proxy on your AWS beanstalk to pull some content off the Godaddy site - in that way everything would go to the single IP address and be proxied on, so you could use a single SSL cert.

Another way would be to take advantage of the way that most SSL Certs are signed for both the base domain and www domain, so, assuming your site was called example.com, you could bind www.domain.com to the AWS beanstalk and domain.com to the Godaddy site.   This might cause some confusion to users though.

A couple of technical things which might help you understand what you can and can't do -

1. A certificate is assoicated with a domain name (or multiple domain
   names), not an IP address.
2. The domain name is generally specified in the "Common Name"/CN field
   of the cert, or in some case the SAN (Subject Alternate Name Field)